# Displaying a JFrame as the result of a JButton click?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to create a `JPanel` to display when a user clicks a button within my main `JFrame`. In Netbeans I first used the wizard to add a new `JPanel` to my project, I then used the GUI creator to fill in all the content. I am not trying to display the `JPanel` with the following code

```
private void m_jbShowSelAccResultsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                      
    Account selAcc = getSelectedAccount();
    if(selAcc != null)
    {
        AccountView accPanel = new AccountView(Account.getDeepCopy(selAcc));
        accPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
        ShowMessage("Please select an account to view");
}
```

But nothing happens, no error is thrown and the `JPanel` is not shown. So I then changed the `JPanel` to a `JFrame` (Netbeans didn't complain). When I try again with the same code I receive the error `GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time`.

How can I display my `JPanel`/`JFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To change views within a Swing GUI, use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as this is a much more robust and reliable way to do this.
2. Don't try to blindly "change a JPanel to a JFrame". It looks like you're just guessing here.
3. GroupLayout can't be reused as the error message is telling you. Likely this error comes from the point above. If you avoid trying to make a JFrame out of a JPanel, the error message will likely go away. As an aside, GroupLayout is not easily used manually, especially if you're trying to add components to an already rendered GUI.

So for instance, if your program had a JPanel say called cardHolderPanel, that used a CardLayout, this held by a variable say called cardLayout, and you've already added a "card" JPanel to this holder for accounts, say called accPanel, and if the accPanel had a method to set its currently displayed account, say `setAccount(Accoint a)`, you could easily swap views by calling the CardLayout `show(...)` method, something like:

```
private void m_jbShowSelAccResultsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    Account selAcc = getSelectedAccount();

    if(selAcc != null) {
        accPanel.setAccount(Account.getDeepCopy(selAcc));
        cardLayout.show(cardHolderPanel, "Account View");
    }
    else {
        showErrorMessage("Please select an account to view");
    }
}
```